# App works locally, crashes on Heroku - Node.JS

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I'm running a simple express app, it is pulling static files from S3, and runs fine locally, but on Heroku it crashes constantly on a warning about permission denied but with no further info.

Is there a way I could find out what is causing the permission error?

Heroku log from deploy to crash:

```
2011-12-26T22:41:14+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-12-26T22:41:19+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 20d0578 by jeffandersen@gmail.com
2011-12-26T22:41:19+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v20 created by jeffandersen@gmail.com
2011-12-26T22:41:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-12-26T22:41:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-12-26T22:41:21+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-12-26T22:41:22+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2011-12-26T22:41:23+00:00 app[web.1]:    info  - socket.io started
2011-12-26T22:41:23+00:00 app[web.1]:    warn  - error raised: Error: EACCES, Permission denied
2011-12-26T22:41:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-12-26T22:41:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
```

Comment: can you post part of the code? are you trying to save files on heroku?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you binding the server port to the environment variable injected by Heroku, `$PORT`?

Comment: I guess Jeff didn't come back, but your answer helped me out, thanks!

Comment: Thanks it works, i modify `app.listen(80)` to `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 80)`

Comment: is there any other reason it could cause this kind of crash?